# KKInput panningGesture giving wrong values when Iphone is tilted

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I'm using KKInput from kobold2d to do some drag and drop using the panning Gesture recognizer. When the iphone is flat on the table it works perfectly, but if I tilt the phone towards me the translation seems completely wrong and no longer behaves normally, in fact it seems to think my IPhone is upside down I think.

Am I doing something wrong?

Sample code:

```
if([input gesturePanBegan])
    {
        for( CCSprite* item in self.View.children )
        {
            bool result = [input isAnyTouchOnNode:item touchPhase: KKTouchPhaseAny];
            if (result)
            {
                itemPanning = item;
                originalPostion = item.position;

            }
        }
        CCLOG(@"%f y translation %f x translation", input.gesturePanTranslation.y , input.gesturePanTranslation.x);
        if(itemPanning != NULL)
        {
            [itemPanning setPosition:ccp(input.gesturePanTranslation.x + originalPostion.x, originalPostion.y)];
            if(input.gesturePanTranslation.x > 70)
            {
                [View Select: [itemPanning tag]];

                SelectAttackCommand * command = [SelectAttackCommand new];
                command.SelectedAttack = [itemPanning tag];

                itemPanning = NULL;

                NOTIFY(command);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(![input gesturePanBegan] && itemPanning != NULL)
    {
        itemPanning = NULL;
        [View Open];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer, but maybe not the best one. In KKInputGesture, under handlePanGesture, the values for translation is calculated as follows:

gesturePanTranslation = [panRecognizer translationInView:glView];
gesturePanTranslation = [self convertRelativePointToGL:gesturePanTranslation];

the second call here translates a value based on the orientation of the device. this may be fine for some scenarios, but in my case it wasn't needed so I commented it out, now my translation values are always correct regardless of how I tilt the IPhone.

I may be missing something here though, so I don't want to mark this as the answer just yet.

Comment: I have commented out gesturePanTranslation  -- = [self convertRelativePointToGL:gesturePanTranslation]; -- and it still doesn't solve my identical problem... huh?

Comment: Tilting phone still breaks your panning?

Comment: Yea. I think it may be a problem with how I make changes to my objects according to the pan. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668685/improper-iphone-orientation/14670540#14670540 if you want to help.